# Regarding continuity

Tags: general-topology

We know that $\tau=\{G\subset \mathbb{N}: n\in G, m\mid n\Rightarrow m\in G\}$ is a topology on $\mathbb{N}$. I have shown that if $m\mid n\Rightarrow f(m)\mid f(n)$, then $f:(\mathbb{N},\tau)\to (\mathbb{N},\tau)$ is continuos. But I couldn't show the converse.

Let $f:(\mathbb{N},\tau)\to (\mathbb{N},\tau)$ be continuous and let $m\mid n$. How to show that $f(m)\mid f(n)$?

Please give a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define, for all $n \in {\mathbb N}$,  $U_n = \{ m \in {\mathbb N} : m | n\}$. First show that $U_n$ is open. Then, given a continuous $f \colon {\mathbb N} \to {\mathbb N}$ and $m | n$, look at $f^{-1}(U_{f(n)})$, which is open because $f$ is continuous. Expand what this means and use $m | n$ to conclude that $f(m) | f(n)$.